# Bitacora en SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, base-de-datos, trigger

Hola amigos una duda lo que pasa es que estoy atorado con estos dos puntos y quisiera saber  como podria elaborarlos, solo quiero la estructura no que me le hagan, vi que para el primero debo crea una biitacora pero es a la hora de elaborar los triggers donde me pierdo si me pudieran orientar un poco se los agradeceria.

1.-Crear un Trigger TR_BitacoraClientes, en donde por cada registro en la tabla de clientes genere una bitácora de respaldo en la tabla BitacoraClientes que guardará el registro que fue modificado, insertado o borrado.

2.-Generar un Stored Procedure SP_AltaFacturaDetalle, tendrá 2 parámetros (NumFactura,
CadenaFacturaDetalle), generará de uno a n registros, en la tabla FacturaDetalle.

Comment: Bienvenido por favor considera leer [ask], de paso hacer el [tour] para conocer mejor como funcionamos, las preguntas que solo incluyen el enunciado de un problema a resolver sin lo que has tratado al momento no on bien vistas y suelen terminar cerradas; te invito a editar y mostrar tu avance

Comment: Estaría bien que añadieras el código que has generado hasta el momento o lo que has intentado...

Answer (score 2):

El trigger.

La sentencia debe de componerse tal que:

```
Create Trigger Tr_BitacoraClientes on dbo.Clientes
After insert,update -- Puedes hacer un trigger after update, insert o dos triggers diferentes
As
-- Sentencias que se ejecutarán en el mismo.
```

Dentro del trigger, cuando se dispara hay dos pseudo tablas que contienen toda la información. Disponen de las mismas columnas que la tabla clientes, y son **inserted** y **deleted**.

En inserted esta toda la información que tiene el registro que se inserta si es nuevo. Y toda la información que tendrá el registro si se hace una update. Por ejemplo inserted.nombre si el registro se esta modificando tendrá el nombre que se cambia. ('Juan')
La pseudo tabla deleted no tiene información si la acción es una insercción, y si dispone de toda la información del registro si se está realizando una update. Pero la que tenía el registro antes de la modificación. En el ejemplo anterior deleted.nombre tenía Pepe para la sentencia update clientes set nombre = 'Juan' where nombre = 'Pepe'

Nota: Los triggers *no son para un registro*, pues tu puedes insertar/modificar varios clientes con la misma sentencia.

Insert into clientes (id, nombre) values (1,'ana'),(2,'bea'); en la pseudo tabla inserted tienes dos filas.

Cuando compongas el código del trigger, tienes que tener esto en cuenta.

Procedimiento almacenado.

```
Create procedure SP_AltaFacturaDetalle (@NumFactura tipoDato, @CadenaFacturaDetalle tipoDato)
As
Begin

End
```

En el cuerpo del procedure tendrás que elaborar tú código.

Comment: Hola y bienvenido a la comunidad. Es maravilloso que quieras aportar pero evitamos responder a preguntas de baja calidad ya que pueden terminar cerradas. En su lugar, orientamos al OP para que se más específico en su pregunta y luego procedemos a responder. Te invito a hacer [el recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para que sepas de lo que hablo.